# Complex situation that no asp.net developer encountered

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I have a div, and some buttons I add on runtime from the master page which is inside that div. All good. But I also need to add a label, dropdown list and a button on the fly because some page which use this master doesn't contain the buttons while some other has buttons.

Now the problem is, if I set the width to a specific value, its accordingly adjusting for the page to align it to the predefined value. Otherwise it assigns to the right. The code is below.

My limitation is, I shouldn't use another div as it adds another line in UI. How to achieve the fixed or variable alignment of these controls relative to the buttons that are visible in certain pages.

Remember, all are in master page. This difficult situation I handled by using &**nbsp however, during resizing it has problems. I also tried new string character overload.

```
     <asp:Label  ID="LiteralSpecial" runat="server" Text="Select page  " width="1070px" style="text-align: right;" Visible="true" ></asp:Label>
     <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlLinks"  runat="server" />
     <asp:Button ID="goButton" runat="server" Text="GO" OnClick="goButton_Click" />
```

I am adding it on the fly

```
    spnContainer.Controls.Add(LiteralSpecial);        
    spnContainer.Controls.Add(ddlLinks);
    spnContainer.Controls.Add(goButton);
```

Comment: Can I just say: best title ever.

Comment: You need to add `AssociatedControlID="ddlLinks"` (which will become a `for` attribute) to that label.

Comment: @Halcyon: For a baby, even ABCD alphabets are so difficult. And I am one.

Comment: @danielnixon: Thank you very much, I am not quite sure how you propose. Could you please help me with the code.

Comment: @Divine: `<asp:Label ID="LiteralSpecial" AssociatedControlID="ddlLinks" ...`. See http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H44.html

Comment: @danielnixon: Thank you, however, it is not helping either

Comment: What do you mean a div adds another line in your ui? Got screenshots?

Comment: @prospector: It means,  our master has already some divs and some design panels, elements, controls so, when I place a div now, it all misaligns

Comment: I am adding it on the fly in master page         spnContainer.Controls.Add(LiteralSpecial);        
        spnContainer.Controls.Add(ddlLinks);
        spnContainer.Controls.Add(goButton);

Comment: Then how does it not misalign when you add three controls? Is there a css style on all your divs?

Comment: @prospector: The users DO NOT WANT to see 3 Div lines in UI, when I keep a Div it add another line. and adds these 3 controls in another line. So, what I did is, adding these controls on the fly like I edited my code above. It is all fine. Except for little alignment problem. Now I need to right align only these 3 controls

Comment: Oh gotcha specify a cssclass propery for these 3 controls, set your alignment to the right in a style

Comment: @prospector: That is what I did .right_align { text-align: right; 
               width: 800px; } and I am afraid it doesn't have any effects? Or am I calling it in wrong place? Where should I call this? I am calling it after adding my 3 controls to span html generic control

Comment: @prospector:    spnContainer.Controls.Add(LiteralSpecial);        
        spnContainer.Controls.Add(ddlLinks);
        spnContainer.Controls.Add(goButton);
        
        #endregion 

        this.pnlButtons.Controls.Add(spnContainer);
        this.pnlButtons.Controls.Add(_createSpacer());
        LiteralSpecial.CssClass = "right_align";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
LiteralSpecial.CssClass="right";
ddlLinks.CssClass="right";
goButton.CssClass="right";

spnContainer.Controls.Add(LiteralSpecial);        
spnContainer.Controls.Add(ddlLinks);
spnContainer.Controls.Add(goButton);
```

Then in your stylesheet put

```
.right{
  float:right;
 }
```

see if that puts you in the right direction

Comment: Hi, this seems to be fairly good, but it the button is not properly visible and also it is little bigger in size. Is there anything can be done like padding etc?

Comment: This looks really good, worked for me. However, it is a problem again with the page that doesn't have any buttons in the div. In those pages, it is all left aligned. Is there a way to apply this same alignment for that page which doesn't have button please?

Comment: I had it worked by setting same css style attribute to those fields. Thank you very much for your kind help, much appreciate it. I had some critical business logic issue that I was working on pointed by my lead, sorry for the delayed response. Your help has a great significance and learning for me, you have a lovely time thank you :)